# Writing Alias in a ZSH For Loop selects only the final loop iteration

Tags: zsh

I'm editing my `.zshrc` file to create aliases for different courses I'm taking at university. I currently do this for 5 courses:

```
alias 301='cd /Users/<...>/university/ELEC301'
```

Because all my courses have the same parent folder, I'm trying to do this as a `for` loop rather than having 10 lines of this same command with a different course code.

I have tried this but I end up getting an alias that only aliases to the last element of the array, despite my `echo` command printing what I expect:

```
courses=(301 302 303)
for course in $courses; do
    echo $course
    alias $course='cd /Users/<...>/university/ELEC${course}'
done
```

In my ZSH terminal, when I run the alias `301`, it consistently directs me to my 303 folder, or whichever is the final element of the array, despite my `echo` printing:

```
301
302
303
```

I've tried writing the array differently, changing the order of the echo, using an intermediate variable. I'm not sure what's going on and appreciate the help.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash`?

Comment: @Cyrus the behavior would be the exact same on bash, I see no reason to remove the tag.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: @mashuptwice, the behavior would be the same, but this question would explicitly accept zsh-only answers. (Also, the code samples from this don't work in bash unedited, on account of `in $courses` instead of `in "${courses[@]}"`, so neither the code in the question nor that in its answers can be used unedited in bash -- in bash, `$courses` is identical to `${courses[0]}`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the explanation, I was not aware of that difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting the variable `course` into single-quotes `'` you prevent your shell from expanding it.

You need to use double-quotes `"` instead.

That:

```
courses=(301 302 303)
for course in $courses; do
    echo "$course"
    alias $course="cd /Users/<...>/university/ELEC$course"
done
```

would work fine.

Comment: @dbirdi Note that you can always use `zsh -x` to get an idea how the variables get expanded